# R Studio - get the summation for the rolling month

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data frame like below, and I want to get the summation(value) for each 4 rolling month.

Edit: In the output I have "2018-12". But it's not shown in the input. It's a typo, my actual data contain "2018-12".

[image]

I prefer to use dplyr:

```
group <- c("red","green","red","red","red","green","green","green","red","green","green","green")
Month <- c("2019-01","2019-02","2019-03","2019-03","2019-05","2019-07","2019-07","2019-08","2019-09","2019-10","2019-10","2019-10")
VALUE <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120)
d_f <- data.frame(group,Month,VALUE)

d_f %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value))
```

Can anyone please help me with how to handle the 4 rolling month? Thanks a lot for your valuable time.

Comment: IN your expected, it is showed the starting for some cases is `'2018-12`, but that is not in the input.  Is there a starting point created somewhere

Comment: Sorry the "2018-12" is not shown in the input. It's a typo when I create the table. It's present in my actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lubridate` you can use `floor_date` and group your dates by 4 month intervals.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

d_f %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste0(Month, '-01'), format = "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(group, startdategroup = floor_date(date, "4 months")) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(VALUE)) %>%
  mutate(enddategroup = startdategroup %m+% months(4) - 1)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   group [2]
  group startdategroup value enddategroup
  <fct> <date>         <dbl> <date>      
1 green 2019-01-01        20 2019-04-30  
2 green 2019-05-01       210 2019-08-31  
3 green 2019-09-01       330 2019-12-31  
4 red   2019-01-01        80 2019-04-30  
5 red   2019-05-01        50 2019-08-31  
6 red   2019-09-01        90 2019-12-31
```

**Edit**: To allow for an "overlap month" (months on the edge of two sequential date intervals), I might take a different approach.

First, I might create a sequence of start and end dates for the intervals (based on minimum and maximum dates in your data frame). The sequence would have date intervals every 4 months.

Then, I would do a `fuzzy_left_join` (using `>=` and `<=` logic) and merge this new data frame with yours. Then a row of data for a single month could be counted twice (once for each of two different intervals).

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

d_f$date = as.Date(paste0(Month, '-01'), format = "%Y-%m-%d")

d_f2 <- data.frame(date_start = seq.Date(min(d_f$date), max(d_f$date), "4 months"))
d_f2$date_end = date_start %m+% months(4)

d_f %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(d_f2, 
                  by = c("date" = "date_start", "date" = "date_end"), 
                  match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`)) %>%
  group_by(group, date_start, date_end) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(VALUE))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   group, date_start [6]
  group date_start date_end   value
  <fct> <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1 green 2019-01-01 2019-05-01    20
2 green 2019-05-01 2019-09-01   210
3 green 2019-09-01 2020-01-01   330
4 red   2019-01-01 2019-05-01   130
5 red   2019-05-01 2019-09-01   140
6 red   2019-09-01 2020-01-01    90
```

Comment: The code works. But I want to have an overlap month. For example, 2019-01 to 2019-04. 2019-04 to 2019-07. So 2019-04 is overlap.

Comment: @vicky Thanks for the clarification. I edited the answer and include an alternative approach for the overlapping month. Let me know if this gives you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the `lag`/`lead` functions in `dplyr`. Something like:

```r
df2 = df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(prev_value = lag(value, 1, order_by = month),
         prev_value2 = lag(value, 2, order_by = month),
         prev_value3 = lag(value, 3, order_by = month)) %>%
  mutate(avg = (value + prev_value + prev_value2 + prev_value3) / 4)
```

And then filter away the intervals you are not interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I run the code but I got this error "Column `prev_value` must be length 7 (the group size) or one, not 12"

Comment: I am unable to replicate your error. Everything runs as  expected with your example data (after making column names consistent). Try updating to the latest version of dplyr. Also check that all your variable names are correct - some of the names in your example are inconsistent (`value` or `VALUE`, `month` or `Month`, etc.)